# Reference for the first name of Sirius Black's mother, known from her portrait: Walburga

Tags: harry-potter, names

In *Order of the Phoenix* chapter 4, we meet the portrait of Sirius's mother in Sirius's house.  The portrait is behind a curtain and starts screaming.  In chapter 6, Sirius tells a few more words about his parents.  Neither place seems to mention the first name of the mother, and just call her Mrs. Black.

Despite of this, some sources on the internet give Mrs. Black's full name as **Walburga Black**: [the Muggle's Guide](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Muggles%27_Guide_to_Harry_Potter/Characters/Walburga_Black), [pt.wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walburga_Black), [a family tree image on en.wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aHarry_Potter_Family_Tree.png), and [harrypotter.wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Walburga_Black).

My question is, what is the canon source that gives the first name?  Is it mentioned somewhere in the books?  In an interview?  On Pottermore?  Some other source?  Or has someone just made it up and everyone else has copied?

Comment: A search of the books shows no mention of her name being Walburga.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"The Noble and Most Ancient House of BLACK," **is a hand-drawn tree** that J.K. Rowling donated to Book Aid International in January of 2006 and auctioned February 22, 2006. [HP LEXICON - BLACK FAMILY TREE](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/blackfamilytree.html).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great.  Where is the first photo from?

Comment: @b_jonas - I just grabbed it via Google images, but it's available at the Lexicon too. I wanted a pic that showed Walburga's name, but since it's so small I included the second image which shows a closer view of JKR's signature at the top of the drawing. Her signature and drawing style is pretty distinctive. :)