# Reference for the first name of Neville Longbottom's grandmother: Augusta Longbottom

Tags: harry-potter, names

Similarly to [Reference for the first name of Sirius Black's mother, known from her portrait: Walburga](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/46203/4918) , I'm asking about the name of a character whose first name doesn't seem to be mentioned in the books.

Neville Longbottom was raised by his grandmother.  She is mentioned many times in the books, first in *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone* chapter 7.  We see more about her in *Order of the Phoenix* chapter 23 and *Deathly Hallows* chapters 29 and 31.  From *Order* chapter 23, we even learn she is Frank Longbottom's mother.

Granny's name is given as **Augusta Longbottom** on some websites.  Is this canon?  What is the primary source of this name?  Does it appear in the books?  Movies?  Movie credits?

Comment: Yup, it's Augusta Longbottom, per the books. She's awfully austere, though ... I would have thought a name like Brunhilda, Prudence, or Mildred might have been appropriate for such a stern lady! :)

Comment: @Slytherincess I don't know. Augusta was the title given to Roman empresses. Some of them would definetely qualify as stern :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Her name was confirmed at least in *Half-Blood Prince* chapter 9 by prof McGonagall, when she discusses with Neville what subjects he should take.

> ‘My grandmother thinks Charms is a soft option,’ mumbled Neville.
>
> ‘Take Charms,’ said Professor McGonagall, ‘and I shall drop Augusta a line reminding her that just because she failed *her* Charms O.W.L., the subject is not necessarily worthless.’

Comment: Fixed it up a bit for you; the quote was from book 6, and the added context makes it clear that "Augusta" is referring to Neville's grandmother

Comment: Is the second quote from a movie script?

Comment: @b_jonas you know, im not 100% sure i found it on the wiki, ill look to verify it otherwise ill edit it out, since jason bakers edit shows the first quote is good enough.

Comment: @b_jonas i took it out for now will check the books tonight.

Comment: chapter 9 i believe, or the end of 8, i pulled that quote up on googles books and got it directly. it would be page 166 on the version of the books google was using.

Comment: Oh, found it, sorry. I'll edit.

Comment: Interesting that "drop a line" refers to writing a letter. I always assumed the phrase came from a phone or telegraph line, not a line of text.

Comment: Her name is mentioned earlier in Half-Blood Prince in the Daily Prophet: *Said Mrs. Augusta 
Longbottom, “My grandson, Neville — a good friend of 
Harry Potter’s, incidentally, who fought the Death 
Eaters alongside him at the Ministry in June and —*

Answer (score 10):

Out of universe, JKR confirmed the name in a cast interview (as well as giving a bit of extra back-story about her confrontation with John Dawlish):

> *SU: You know, Jo, he idolizes a man, an auror guy who got pwned by an
>   old lady wearing a dead bird on her head, you know, on her hat. Now,
>   come on!*
>
> *JN: They don't understand this, Jo. I know we've talked about this.
>   They don't understand the night that this-- They call it a duel. It
>   wasn't a duel. At least in my mind anyway, I think it needs a little
>   explaining of how somebody as, you know, as skillful as Dawlish, you
>   know, could've got taken down like this.*
>
> ...
>
> **JKR:** ***By the time Augusta Longbottom got to him, he had been-- several people had attacked Dawlish. I mean, I think he was a bit
>   punch-drunk by that point, you know. He had become a favorite
>   punch-bag of the Order of the Phoenix by then. So I don't think he was
>   firing on all cylinders. But I really saw Mrs. Longbottom as a
>   powerful witch. So, um, sorry.*** - [Pottercast Interview](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/1217-pottercast-anelli.html)

The actress [portraying the character](http://www.mugglenet.com/2010/05/actress-ninette-finch-cast-as-augusta-longbottom/) in the film also explicitly named her;

> *Our friends at Snitch Seeker have confirmed that actress Ninette Finch was cast as Neville Longbottom’s grandmother in Deathly Hallows.
>   Finch was also involved in Half-Blood Prince as an extra.*
>   ”Yes I am playing Augusta Longbottom, although it is not a very big part… I have also played a couple of witches and was one of the people on the Millennium bridge when it was under attack,” *Finch said.*